# Create a union from two generic type parameters

Tags: typescript, type-inference

The following snippet correctly infers `change$`'s return type as `Observable<'A' | 'B' | 'X' | 'Y'>`.

```
getChange$() {
  return merge(
    this.propertyA, // Observable<'A' | 'B'>
    this.propertyB  // Observable<'X' | 'Y'>
  );
}
```

But, can I still specify the return type is an `Observable` *without* having to know `propertyA` and `propertyB`'s type parameter?

Can I specify the type is `Observable` but let TypeScript infer the type parameter still?

```
getChange$(): Observable<?>
```

Or can I get the type from the properties and union them?

```
getChange$(): Observable<genericTypeOf(propertyA) | genericTypeOf(propertyB)>
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually in methods `this` parameter is defined implicitly, but you can also define it explicitly which would allow you to extract necessary type parameter out of properties.

```
class Foo {
    propertyA: Observable<'A' | 'B'> = null as any;
    propertyB: Observable<'X' | 'Y'> = null as any;
    getChange$<T, U>(this: { propertyA: Observable<T>, propertyB: Observable<U> }): Observable<T | U> {
        return merge(
            this.propertyA,
            this.propertyB
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not working for me unfortunately. I get this error: "Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:26)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

Comment: @BetaKeja there was indeed a problem with my previous solution. I'be updated to a different approach that should work for you.

Comment: I guess I simplified my example too much. My `Observable`s are actually properties on the class's properties; one of them is also optional and a union with a string literal. . . I think this may be more complicated than it's worth for my situation.

Comment: Does your first solution work in later versions of typescript? I've since noticed some strange things with the typescript version. I think vscode checked some parts with 3.2.2 and others with 2.7.2 (not to mention the project should be using 2.9.2) :S

Comment: @BetaKeja conditional types are only available starting with TypeScript 2.8

Comment: After fixing the TS version problem (it's now 2.9.2) I tried out your first solution and it works. Although I had to change the `this`s to the types with the observable properties.